# Mode in R by groups

Tags: r, function, mode

I need to calculate the mode of an identity number for each group of ages. Let's suposse the following table:

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(age=c(12,12,3,3,12),v=rnorm(5), number=c("122","125","5","5","122"))
```

So I created a function:

```
g <- function(number) {
      ux <- unique(number)
      ux[which.max(tabulate(match(number, ux)))]
    }
H<-function(tabla){data.frame(MODA=g, count=nrow(tabla))}
clasif_edad1<-ddply(DF,.(age), H)
View(clasif_edad1)
```

But I ge tthe following error:

```
Error: arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

The output should be:

```
age      v    number moda
12  0,631152199 122 122
12  0,736648714 125 122
3   0,545921527 5   5
3   0,59336284  5   5
12  0,836685437 122 122
```

Don't know what the problem is.

Thanks

Comment: Your function is a bit unclear. Can you show your desired output. And again, there is no reason whatsoever to convert `data.table` into a `data.frame` and then use `plyr`. `data.table` is the king of R, just use it as is

Comment: If you want us to reproduce your column `v`, you need to use `set.seed`, because `rnorm` generates a random seed each time you run it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach:

```
> myfun <- function(x) unique(x)[which.max(table(x))]
> DT[ , moda := myfun(number), by = age]
> DT
   age          v number moda
1:  12 -0.9740026    122  122
2:  12  0.6893727    125  122
3:   3 -0.9558391      5    5
4:   3 -1.2317071      5    5
5:  12 -0.9568919    122  122
```

Comment: This seems the idiomatic way to do this with `data.table`.

Comment: I'm working with around ~4MM rows of data, and this is taking a very long time to run -- finding modes for ~4 values by groups is increasing the time it takes for me to create a new datatable with ~10 other variables by a factor of 6. Is there a way to find modes more efficiently? Right now my plan is just to either downsample, or just let the program run overnight.

Comment: @verybadatthis I suppose there is no faster way in R,

Comment: I actually, after writing this, [found a somewhat faster way detailed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29686198/find-number-of-occurrences-of-modal-value-for-a-group-using-data-table-r?noredirect=1#comment47516128_29686198) It is very similar to what you did here, just slightly more vectorized and split up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr`for this:

```
library(dplyr)
modes_by_age <- summarise(group_by(DT, age), group_mode = g(number))
inner_join(DT, modes_by_age)
```

This gives your desired output:

```
Source: local data table [5 x 4]

  age         v number group_mode
1   3 0.5524352      5          5
2   3 0.2869912      5          5
3  12 0.8987475    122        122
4  12 0.9740715    125        122
5  12 2.5058450    122        122
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R solution. You could compute the mode for each group and then merge with your original data:

```
merge(DT, setNames(aggregate(number~age, data=DT, g), c("age", "moda")), by="age")
#    age          v number moda
# 1:   3  1.7148357      5    5
# 2:   3  0.9504811      5    5
# 3:  12 -0.7648237    122  122
# 4:  12  0.9011115    125  122
# 5:  12 -0.8718779    122  122
```

There may be a data table-specific approach, but this would work even if `DT` were a data frame.

Answer (score 0):

```
modef <- function(V)
{ 
k = 1
prev='xxxx'
max_value = 0
for (i in V)
{
if (prev == i)
{ 
k = k+1
}
else
{
if (k > max_value) 
{
MODE_CALC = data.frame( 
number = c(prev) , 
occurence = c(k) )
max_value = k
k = 1
}
k = 1
}
prev = i
}
print(MODE_CALC$number)
}
V = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 14, 14, 14, 15, 16, 17, 17, 17 ,17 , 
17, 18, 19)    
modef(sort(V))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(janitor)
mode_ <- function(x) tabyl(x) |> filter(n == max(n)) |> pull(x) |> head(1)
```

Comment: It would help if you explain what this does, particularly the advantage of using janitor over base table