# Rearrange rows and calculate mode in R by creating a new variable

Tags: r, summary

I have a dataset with two columns, "ID" and "CODCOM" with about 1 milion of rows. The first column "ID"  contain duplicate values.

| ID | CODCOM |
| --- | --- |
| 10000 | 12 |
| 101010 | 14 |
| 201020 | 11 |
| 201020 | 11 |
| 201020 | 12 |
| 324032 | 43 |
| 324032 | 43 |
| 324032 | 43 |
| 405044 | 51 |
| 323032 | 21 |

I want to group "ID" duplicated values in different groups, then calculate the mode for each groups, after that I want to create a new column with the related mode values. Something like this:

| ID | CODCOM | NEW_COL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 12 | 12 |
| 101010 | 14 | 14 |
| 201020 | 11 | 11 |
| 201020 | 11 | 11 |
| 201020 | 12 | 11 |
| 324032 | 43 | 43 |
| 324032 | 43 | 43 |
| 324032 | 43 | 43 |
| 405044 | 51 | 51 |
| 323032 | 21 | 43 |

How can I do this in an easy way?

Thank you so much in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Does this related question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791018/mode-in-r-by-groups

Comment: Or, if those approaches aren't fast enough, another alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29686203/6851825

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dplyr approach where I join the data to a version of itself with just the most-common CODCOM value (or first appearing with ties).

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  left_join(
    df1 %>%
      group_by(ID) %>%
      count(mode = CODCOM, sort = TRUE) %>%
      slice(1),
    by = "ID"
  )


       ID CODCOM mode n
1   10000     12   12 1
2  101010     14   14 1
3  201020     11   11 2
4  201020     11   11 2
5  201020     12   11 2
6  324032     43   43 3
7  324032     43   43 3
8  324032     43   43 3
9  405044     51   51 1
10 323032     21   21 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find below one solution using the package `data.table`:

**REPREX**

- Code

```r
library(data.table)


# Function to compute mode
mode_compute <- function(x) {
  uniqx <- unique(x)
  uniqx[which.max(tabulate(match(x, uniqx)))]
}

# Compute mode by ID
DT[ , MODE := mode_compute(CODCOM), by = ID]
```

- Output

```r
DT
#>         ID CODCOM MODE
#>  1:  10000     12   12
#>  2: 101010     14   14
#>  3: 201020     11   11
#>  4: 201020     11   11
#>  5: 201020     12   11
#>  6: 324032     43   43
#>  7: 324032     43   43
#>  8: 324032     43   43
#>  9: 405044     51   51
#> 10: 323032     21   21
```

- Data:

```r
# Data
DT <- data.table(ID = c("10000", "101010", "201020", "201020", "201020",
                 "324032", "324032", "324032", "405044", "323032"),
                 CODCOM = c(12, 14, 11, 11, 12, 43, 43, 43, 51, 21))
DT
#>         ID CODCOM
#>  1:  10000     12
#>  2: 101010     14
#>  3: 201020     11
#>  4: 201020     11
#>  5: 201020     12
#>  6: 324032     43
#>  7: 324032     43
#>  8: 324032     43
#>  9: 405044     51
#> 10: 323032     21
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly: we could `group_by` `ID` and then use `summarise` the `mode` of the mode function:

If you don't want to `summarise` you could use  `mutate` instead (will keep all rows)!

```
library(dplyr)

mode <- function(codes){
  which.max(tabulate(codes))
}

df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(NEW_COL = mode(CODCOM))
```

```
      ID NEW_COL
   <int>   <int>
1  10000      12
2 101010      14
3 201020      11
4 323032      21
5 324032      43
6 405044      51
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
# Option 1 using TarJae's mode function:
# Apply the function groupwise, store result as vector:
# NEW_COL => integer vector
df$NEW_COL <- with(
  df,
  ave(
    CODCOM,
    ID,
    FUN = function(x){
      which.max(tabulate(x))
    }
  )
)

# Option two:
# Function to calculate the mode of a vector: 
# mode_statistic => function()
mode_statistic <- function(x){
  # Calculate the mode: res => vector
  res <- names(
    head(
      sort(
        table(
          x
        ),
        decreasing = TRUE
      ),
      1
    )
  )
  # Explicitly define returned object: character vector => env
  return(res)
}

# Apply the function groupwise, store result as vector:
# NEW_COL => integer vector
df$NEW_COL <- with(
  df,
  ave(
    CODCOM,
    ID,
    FUN = function(x){
      as.integer(
        mode_statistic(x)
      )
    }
  )
)
```